# Character in Buffy (possibly Angel) who could not lie

Tags: character-identification, buffy-the-vampire-slayer, angel

I can't remember if this character was in Buffy or Angel, but I'm pretty sure I remember he was talking *to* Angel.

Angel had enlisted his help to accomplish some task. His schtick was he absolutely couldn't lie, so he hated being asked questions, someone asks him a question and he quickly answers and immediately tells that person that if they try to ask another, he'd kill them.

He looks like a regular human man and carries a sword.

I've always wondered if this guy was based on a *real* mythological character or if he was created just for the show.

Anyone know who I'm talking about?

Comment: The title is spot-on.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is [Drogyn](http://buffy.wikia.com/wiki/Drogyn), the keeper of the Deeper Well, otherwise known as the Battlebrand and notably as the "Truthsayer" due to his inability to lie.

The scene you're recalling is probably from the episode "[A Hole in the World](http://www.buffyworld.com/angel/transcripts/103_tran.html)"

> **DROGYN:** *I just said to you, not one moment ago, don't ask.*
>
> **ANGEL:** *Seriously. He doesn't like questions.*
>
> **SPIKE:** *Why the bloody hell not?*
>
> **ANGEL:** ***He can't lie.***

[image]

---

As far as his mythical origins are concerned, his character is evidently a creation of the writers. The commentary for the episode mentions that he was cast after Anthony Head (Rupert Giles) was unable to appear due to scheduling conflicts. They gave him the "*can't lie*" schtick to explain why the crew would implicitly believe him, despite him being a wholly new character.

Comment: Cheers Richard, great explanation too.